# Getting UNDEFINED when using a Map within a Map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I use a json file of matches and live score like that:

```
   [
    {
    "league": {
        "id": 722,
        "name": "Liga Premier Serie A",
        "country": "Mexico",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/722.png",
        "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/mx.svg",
        "season": 2023,
        "round": "Group 2 - 19"
    },
    "teams": [
        {
            "home": {
                "id": 17787,
                "name": "Lobos ULMX",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/17787.png",
                "winner": null
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 15932,
                "name": "Irapuato",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/15932.png",
                "winner": null
            }
        },
        {
            "home": {
                "id": 15937,
                "name": "Reboceros La Piedad",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/15937.png",
                "winner": false
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 15936,
                "name": "Pioneros de Cancún",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/15936.png",
                "winner": true
            }
        },
        {
            "home": {
                "id": 19905,
                "name": "CDS Tampico Madero",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/19905.png",
                "winner": true
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 22045,
                "name": "Petroleros de Salamanca",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22045.png",
                "winner": false
            }
        },
        {
            "home": {
                "id": 17788,
                "name": "Montañeses",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/17788.png",
                "winner": true
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 22043,
                "name": "Aguacateros de Peribán",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22043.png",
                "winner": false
            }
        },
        {
            "home": {
                "id": 15919,
                "name": "Atlético Saltillo",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/15919.png",
                "winner": null
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 19909,
                "name": "Mexicali FC",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/19909.png",
                "winner": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "goals": [
        {
            "home": 0,
            "away": 0
        },
        {
            "home": 1,
            "away": 2
        },
        {
            "home": 2,
            "away": 1
        },
        {
            "home": 3,
            "away": 2
        },
        {
            "home": 0,
            "away": 0
        }
    ],
    "score": [
        {
            "halftime": {
                "home": 0,
                "away": 0
            },
            "fulltime": {
                "home": 0,
                "away": 0
            },
            "extratime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "penalty": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            }
        },
        {
            "halftime": {
                "home": 1,
                "away": 1
            },
            "fulltime": {
                "home": 1,
                "away": 2
            },
            "extratime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "penalty": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            }
        },
        {
            "halftime": {
                "home": 1,
                "away": 0
            },
            "fulltime": {
                "home": 2,
                "away": 1
            },
            "extratime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "penalty": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            }
        },
        {
            "halftime": {
                "home": 1,
                "away": 1
            },
            "fulltime": {
                "home": 3,
                "away": 2
            },
            "extratime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "penalty": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            }
        },
        {
            "halftime": {
                "home": 0,
                "away": 0
            },
            "fulltime": {
                "home": 0,
                "away": 0
            },
            "extratime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "penalty": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "venue": [
        {
            "id": 1072,
            "name": "Estadio Miguel Alemán Valdés",
            "city": "Celaya"
        },
        {
            "id": 11250,
            "name": "Estadio Juan N. López",
            "city": "La Piedad"
        },
        {
            "id": 1086,
            "name": "Estadio Tamaulipas",
            "city": "Tampico y Ciudad Madero"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "Estadio de la Sociedad Cuauhtemoc Moctezuma",
            "city": "Orizaba"
        },
        {
            "id": 11237,
            "name": "Estadio Olímpico Francisco I. Madero",
            "city": "Saltillo"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "league": {
        "id": 872,
        "name": "Liga Premier Serie B",
        "country": "Mexico",
        "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/872.png",
        "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/mx.svg",
        "season": 2023,
    ....
 ]
```

I use map within another map to get data:

```
newData?.map((match, index) => (

.......

 [match]?.map((d, index) => (  // when I use match.teams.map((... I get all element but only under "teams" but other elements as "goals" I get "undefined"

  <h3>{d?.teams?.home?.name}</h3>
  <div>{d?.goals?.home}</div>
 ))
 .....
))
```

I tried to get data of different elements in json format but I get `undefined` or `cannot read properties`.

For example, if I use `match.teams.map((d, index)` I get all elements under `teams` but I can't get data under `goals` or `score`.

When I do `[match]?.map((d, index) => (` I can get any elements under `teams` or any other specific fields.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `teams` and `goals` are *arrays*. They don't have `.home` properties so writing code like `d?.teams?.home` will give `undefined` (arrays have properties such as `.length`, etc.). When you do `match.teams.map()` you're accessing and mapping the objects within the teams array, so you won't have access to the objects in `goals` unless you access them specifically.

It looks like you want to relate each `team` object to a `goals` object using the index:

```
newData?.map((match, index) => (
  match.teams?.map((team, index) => (<React.Fragment key={/* unique and consistent key for each team, eg: team.home.id */}>
    <h3>{team.home?.name}</h3>
    <div>{match.goals[index]?.home}</div>
  </React.Fragment>))
  .....
))
```

Here `match.goals[index]?.home` will look at the `goals` array and grab the corresponding goal object from it that relates to the current `team` using the `index`.